# Appcelerator Titanium Windows Mobile Module Development

Tags: windows, mobile, module, titanium, appcelerator

I have a need to create a mobile module project for Windows using Appcelerator Titanium, I have created modules for Android and ios in the past, but this is the first time I have needed to create one for Windows.

I clicked the option to create a new mobile module and the dialog (image attached) opened which only offered the option to create a module for Android or Mobile Web, there was no option to create a Windows Module.

[image: New module screenshot]

I have checked that I meet Appcelerator's requirements, details below.

I have installed SDK 5.4.0.GA and wondered if this is as a result of Appcelerator's transitioning from Compiling with the 8.1 SDK to the Windows 10 SDK.

Has anyone managed to create a new module since installing 5.4.0.GA?

System:

```
Windows 10 Build 14915

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015  Version 14.0.25425.01 Update 3.

Microsoft .NET Framework  Version 4.6.02001.

Windows Phone SDK 8.0 - ENU.

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   7.5.00830.1

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)   14.1.11107.0

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.40314.0

Common Azure Tools   1.8

GitHub.VisualStudio   1.0

JavaScript Language Service   2.0

JavaScript Project System   2.0

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4

Multilingual App Toolkit   4.0.1605.0

NuGet Package Manager   3.4.4

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2

SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.60519.0

TypeScript   1.8.36.0

Visual C++ for Cross Platform Mobile Development   1.0

Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   14.0.25527.01

Xamarin   4.1.1.3 (34a92cd)

Xamarin.Android   6.1.1.1 (7db2aac)

Xamarin.iOS   9.8.1.4 (3cf8aae)

Appcelerator Titanium 

Appcelerator Studio Version: 4.7.0.201607250649

Titanium SDK Version: 5.5.0.v20160906154554

Titanium SDK Version: 5.4.0.GA

Titanium SDK Version: 5.3.1.GA

Studio Diagnostics:

ENV:

USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=DES-LAPTOP2

LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Des\AppData\Local

PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6

FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO

VS140COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\

USERDOMAIN=DES-LAPTOP2

FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING=Internet Explorer

LOGONSERVER=\\DES-LAPTOP2

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20

SESSIONNAME=Console

ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData

PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86

VS120COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\
PSModulePath=C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\

SystemDrive=C:

APPDATA=C:\Users\Des\AppData\Roaming

USERNAME=Des

ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)

CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files

Path=C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_40/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_40/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_40/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;D:\Android\sdk;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Users\Des\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Des\AppData\Roaming\npm;;C:\Users\Des\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Appcelerator Studio;

FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING=Default

PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

OS=Windows_NT

PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432=AMD64

COMPUTERNAME=DES-LAPTOP2

PROCESSOR_REVISION=3c03

CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files

ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe

ProgramData=C:\ProgramData

ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files

HOMEPATH=\Users\Des

SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS

TEMP=C:\Users\Des\AppData\Local\Temp

HOMEDRIVE=C:

PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel

USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Des

TMP=C:\Users\Des\AppData\Local\Temp

VS110COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files

ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86)

PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public

NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8

windir=C:\WINDOWS
```

Comment: Does the dashboard in studio say Windows Phone SDK is installed?

Comment: Yes, I have no problems creating Windows Mobile Applications, it's just creating a Module that is an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Studio does not currently support Windows module development. It is planned to be introduced in version 4.8.0 which will ship alongside SDK 6.0.0 in November. For now modules can be created using the CLI, appc new and then follow the prompts, and then built with appc run -p windows.

Comment: I tried the CLI,  It tried to create a module, but failed. Following the Appcelerator guide command line call there is no option to select the module target platform. It  tries to create a blank module for all  platforms.  This fails and complains "TypeError: Invalid Version: android.0.0".  This is annoying as this box has a valid Android SDK & NDK installed, I use this box for native Android development & I don't want a Titanium Android module. I recall that Titanium for Android requires an old obsolete SDK, do I have to install that to create a Windows module?

Comment: OK, I have got a module built.  Yes, you do have to have a fully functional Android setup to build a Windows module.  And as a bonus it has to be on the C: drive so my existing Native setup was no good.  Nearly 40GB of unused clutter on my C: drive and everything works great.  Thanks Appcelerator for never considering developers might have a computer with more than 1 hard drive.Ewan, Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction.